# PyPac PyInstaller can't access the internet

Tags: python, python-3.x, httprequest, pyinstaller, proxy-server

I've got a program that access the Internet via a proxy server and I'm using PyPac's PACSession for the session. This works fine when I'm calling the program with python. However, compiling it with pyinstaller gives me an error.

Test program:

```
import sys
import os
from pypac import PACSession
from requests.auth import HTTPProxyAuth
import getpass
import keyring
url = r'https://leilookup.gleif.org/api/v1/leirecords?lei='
lei_list = ['I9O8MELCUVOTLJABOX92', '5493004NRE4TCTRC2D29', 'VBHFXSYT7OG62HNT8T76', '529900M2YBAPOUTTM178', '549300KJFL0KHN20KH82',
            '0NTV4GLMGXKW55GJC835']

def main():
    lei_numbers = ",".join(lei_list)
    internet = 'gleif.org'
    password = keyring.get_password(internet, getpass.getuser())
    if not password:
        keyring.set_password(internet, getpass.getuser(), getpass.getpass('Please enter your Login password: '))
    print('Before PACSession')
    session = PACSession(proxy_auth=HTTPProxyAuth(getpass.getuser(), keyring.get_password(internet, getpass.getuser())))
    page = session.get(url=url + lei_numbers)
    json = page.json()
    for ix in range(len(json)):
        print(json[ix]['LEI']['$'] + ': ' + json[ix]['Entity']['LegalName']['$'])

    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

Versions:

```
Windows 7
python 3.6.3 
pypack 0.5.0
pyinstaller 3.3
requests 2.18.4
tld 0.7.9;
```

Errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\tld\utils.py", line 117, in get_tld_names
  File "c:\python36\lib\codecs.py", line 895, in open
    file = builtins.open(filename, mode, buffering)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '...\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI299882\\tld\\res\\effective_t
ld_names.dat.txt'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "urllib\request.py", line 1318, in do_open
  File "http\client.py", line 1239, in request
  File "http\client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
  File "http\client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
  File "http\client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
  File "http\client.py", line 964, in send
  File "http\client.py", line 936, in connect
  File "socket.py", line 724, in create_connection
  File "socket.py", line 713, in create_connection
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of ti
me, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\tld\utils.py", line 74, in update_tld_names
  File "urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
  File "urllib\request.py", line 526, in open
  File "urllib\request.py", line 544, in _open
  File "urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
  File "urllib\request.py", line 1346, in http_open
  File "urllib\request.py", line 1320, in do_open
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly resp
ond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ScreenScraping.py", line 51, in <module>
  File "ScreenScraping.py", line 41, in main
  File "site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 521, in get
  File "site-packages\pypac\api.py", line 179, in request
  File "site-packages\pypac\api.py", line 244, in get_pac
  File "site-packages\pypac\api.py", line 48, in get_pac
  File "site-packages\pypac\api.py", line 72, in collect_pac_urls
  File "site-packages\pypac\wpad.py", line 31, in proxy_urls_from_dns
  File "site-packages\tld\utils.py", line 169, in get_tld
  File "site-packages\tld\utils.py", line 124, in get_tld_names
  File "site-packages\tld\utils.py", line 84, in update_tld_names
tld.exceptions.TldIOError: <urlopen error [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly
respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>
[29744] Failed to execute script ScreenScraping
```

What can I do to get the compiled program working with pyinstaller?

Answer (score 1):

Your actual issue is:

```py
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '...\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI299882\\tld\\res\\effective_tld_names.dat.txt'
```

Basically, the `tld` package used by `pypac` loads that text file and once packed with PyInstaller, the file is no longer available. You can include it in your PyInstaller binary either with the `--add-data` flag or the `datas` field in the spec file.

```py
datas: [('C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\tld\res\effective_tld_names.dat.txt', 'tld\res')]
```

Comment: also the strings should have the r"some string" prefix

Answer (score 0):

If you try to copy paste the solution from above answer it won't work try this and make sure to change your python path appropriately

```
datas= [('C:\\Python\\Lib\\site-packages\\tld\\res\\effective_tld_names.dat.txt', 'tld\\res')]
```